# Need help increasing performance and responsiveness in PyGame regarding clicks (MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, pygame

I'm trying to re-create chess inside of python using PyGame and currently, I've been working on the mechanics of being able to move pieces around. I've chosen to begin with scripting the Knight's movement as it's movement is the most complicated out of all the chess pieces. I've successfully created a system where the player can select the piece and move it accordingly to any spot on the grid. The player can also unselect the piece should they choose to decide not to move it in the end. I haven't coded all the possible ways the knight could move; only a couple of them; but the primary issue here is that the responses are extremely slow. What I mean is that I'm having to click multiple times to get a piece to be 'selected' or to unselected and more times to get to move to the spot desired. I think it has something to do with calling a function in the update which involves using a for loop to cycle through pygame's events to detect mouse down events but I am not entirely sure. Any help on improving responses would be greatly appreciated! Note: I am importing the code for the pieces into the main game program as well as importing the main code into select methods in the Knight class to access some important variables such as `pGrid` and methods such as `player_updategrid()`

Main Game Logic:

```
import pygame
import pieces
import itertools
import numpy as np


#2050/8 = 256.25
#2050/960 = 2.135
WINWIDTH = 960
WINHEIGHT = 960
WHITE = (200,200,200)
LIGHTTAN = (247, 245, 218)
BROWN = (158, 114, 73)

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((WINWIDTH,WINHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption('Chess')
run = True
bPieces = pygame.sprite.Group()
wPieces = pygame.sprite.Group()
bKnight = pieces.knight(win, 7, 7)
bPieces.add(bKnight)
pgrid = []

#SET UP THE BOARD
board = np.ones((3,3))
board = np.zeros((8,8),dtype=int)
board[1::2,::2] = 1
board[::2,1::2] = 1
def bgupdategrid():
    for row in range(0,8):
        for column in range(0,8):
            if board[row][column] == 1:
                pygame.draw.rect(win, (LIGHTTAN),
                                    (((column * (WINWIDTH) // 8)), ((row * (WINWIDTH) // 8))
                                    , (WINWIDTH - 24) // 8, (WINHEIGHT - 24) // 8))
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(win, (BROWN),
                                 (((column * (WINWIDTH) // 8)), ((row * (WINWIDTH) // 8))
                                  , (WINWIDTH - 24) // 8, (WINHEIGHT - 24) // 8))


def player_updategrid(pos = None):
    for row in range(0,8):
        pgrid.append([])
        for column in range(0,8):

            pgrid[row].append(0)
            if pgrid[row][column] == 1 and pos == 'y':
                return ((column * (WINWIDTH) // 8) + column * 2)
            elif pgrid[row][column] == 1 and pos == 'x':
                return ((row * (WINWIDTH) // 8) + row * 2)

while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


    #UPDATE BOARD UI
    bgupdategrid()




    #UPDATE PIECE DISPLAY



    bPieces.draw(win)
    player_updategrid()
    bPieces.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Code for the Knight Piece:

```
import pygame

class knight(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, surface, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.surface = surface
        self.image = pygame.image.load("D:\PythonProjects\Chess\Assets/blackKnight.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (120,120))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 120,120)  #self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.selected = False
    def update(self):
        import main as m
        self.move()
        m.pgrid[self.x][self.y] = 1
        self.rect.x = m.player_updategrid('x')
        self.rect.y = m.player_updategrid('y')


    def getmouse(self):
        getmouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        mposx = getmouse[0]
        mposy = getmouse[1]
        return mposx//120, mposy//120
    def move(self):
        import main as m
        mposx, mposy = self.getmouse()
        #print(self.selected)
        if mposy == self.y and mposx == self.x and self.selected is False:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if self.selected == False:
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        print('selected')
                        self.selected = True
        elif mposy == self.y and mposx == self.x and self.selected == True:
            #print('yoyoyoyo')
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    print('unselected')
                    self.selected = False
        elif mposy != self.y and mposx != self.x and self.selected is True:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    print(mposx, mposy)
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        if (((self.x - 2) == mposx) and ((self.y - 1) == mposy)) or (((self.x - 2) == mposx) and ((self.y - 1) == mposy)):
                            #print('hi')
                            m.pgrid[self.x][self.y] = 0
                            self.x = mposx
                            self.y = mposy
                            self.selected = False
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are handling the user-input-event for the `Knight` in the `Knight.move()` function.  This is *not* where this should go.  It's best to have only a single place to handle user input, then decide where that input needs to go based on the state of the game at the time.  A good place for this code, is the main loop.

Currently the events are only being checked during the split-second that `Knight.move()` function is called, so probably *most of the time*, events are not being handled, and this is what's making it difficult to click.  You really don't want the player's input handling spread throughout 6 different implementations of a chess piece types.

So... the code needs some significant re-structuring.  But first let's add some utility functions:

Add a second 2D list to hold the logical position of all your pieces.  How about it either holds `None` for an empty cell, or a reference to the `Sprite` object (e.g.: `Knight`) if that cell is occupied.  For example:

```
# Create an empty board
board_pieces = []
for i in range( 8 ):
    board_pieces.append( [None] * 8 )
```

Maybe you have this already, but I couldn't see it.  Then we will write a function that can take a mouse-click, and determine if that click was on a piece.  But first we need to convert a mouse co-ordinate to a board co-ordinate, and back again.

```
def windowToBoardCoord( win_x, win_y ):
    """ Convert the window co-ordinates to board co-ordinates """
    board_x = win_x // ( WINDOW_WIDTH  // 8 )
    board_y = win_y // ( WINDOW_HEIGHT // 8 )
    # Debugging, comment out later when it all works
    print( "Window (%d,%d) => Board (%d,%d)" % ( win_x, win_y, board_x, board_y ) )
    return board_x, board_y

def boardToWindowCoord( board_x, board_y ):
    """ Convert the board co-ordinates to window co-ordinates """
    # NOTE: returns the top-left corner
    win_x = board_x * 8
    win_y = board_y * 8
    # Debugging, comment out later when it all works
    print( "Board (%d,%d) => Window (%d,%d)" % ( board_x, board_y, win_x, win_y ) )
    return win_x, win_y

def getPieceAt( board, board_x, board_y ):
    """ Get the piece on the board, or None """
    any_piece = board[board_y][board_x]    # could be None
    # Debugging, comment out later when it all works
    if ( any_piece == None ):
        print( "No piece at board[%d][%d]" % ( board_y, board_x ) )
    else:
        print( "Piece [%s] is at board[%d][%d]here" % ( str( any_piece ), board_y, board_x  ) )
    return any_piece
```

This allows us to see a mouse-click, get the mouse-position, then determine where this clicked the board.

We will add a variable named `current_selection` to keep the currently selected player piece, which is initially `None`.

So back to the main event loop:

```
current_selection = None     # any piece the player has selected

while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:   # user clicked the mouse
            mouse_x, mouse_y = event.pos             # where was it clicked
            board_x, board_y = windowToBoardCoord( mouse_x, mouse_y )

            # Is there a piece at those co-ordinates?
            piece = getPieceAt( board_pieces, board_x, board_y )

            # If the player has already selected a piece, this is a move
            # to that new location
            if ( current_selected != None ):
                if ( piece == current_selected ):
                    # clicked on the same piece twice, un-select it
                    current_selected = None
                else:
                    # This is a move, but is it valid?
                    if ( current_selected.isLegalMove( board_pieces, board_x, board_y )
                        # Valid move
                        # Update the board ( maybe this should be a function )
                        current_x, current_y = current_selected.getBoardPosition()
                        board[ current_y ][ current_x ] = None
                        board[ board_y ][ board_x ]     = current_selected
                        # Update the screen
                        current_selected.moveTo( board_x, board_y )
                        # ... handle taking pieces, etc. TODO  
            elif ( piece != None ):
                # Nothing selected, is this a new selection
                if ( piece.isOwnedByPlayer() ):
                    current_selected = piece
                else:
                    # can't select opponents pieces
                    makeErrorBeep()
                 

    #UPDATE BOARD UI
    bgupdategrid()

    ...
```

This leaves the Knight Sprite quite a bit simpler.  It just needs to have an `image` and `rect`, but also implement the various rules for this type of piece.

```
class Knight( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__( self, x, y, colour ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.name = 'Knight'
        # TODO: use os.path.join() here ~
        self.image = pygame.image.load("D:\PythonProjects\Chess\Assets/blackKnight.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (120,120))
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = ( x, y )

    def update(self):
        # image does not change (yet)
        pass

    def moveTo( self, board_x, board_y ):
        win_x, win_y = boardToWindowCoord( board_x, board_y )
        self.rect.topleft = ( win_x, win_y )

    def getBoardPosition( self ):
        x, y = self.rect.topleft
        board_x, board_y = windowToBoardCoord( x, y )
        return board_x, board_y

    def isLegalMove( self, board, move_x, move_y ):
        """ Is it a legal move from current-position to (x,y) """
        board_x, board_y = self.getBoardPostion()

        # TODO: check all those L-shaped movements
        #       Can we move from (board_x, board_y) to (move_x, move_y)
        result = True   # TODO: just accept any movement for testing
        return result
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! This seems like such an excellent solution! Thank you for such an in-depth answer! I have one question though. How and where do I actually make a piece take up a spot on the board_pieces 2D array?

Comment: @Azerox - Your board is just a 2D list, so you can put anything in it.  So you could just use it to hold sprites.  Something like: `board_pieces[7][0] = Rook( WHITE )`  `board_pieces[7][1] = Knight( WHITE )`, etc.

Comment: In the second to last else statement in the main loop code, piece.isOwnedByPlayer is not an actual method. I understand I could make my own method but even then I would get an error message because most spots on the grid are None, not actual class objects that have methods.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you reduce the number of nested loops in your code by:

- only update the rectangle of the piece moved (before and after ) so you'll need 2 variables to store the old and the new position of the selected piece. so that you reduce the iterations during the update.
- remove the matrix you used to know which color there is ( you can keep it i you want to setit up and place the position of other pieces so that you don't put a piece on top of another one -of the same color-) but to choose the color you can use the position (x and y ) example : `if x+y %2 == 0`  that means it's white and `else` then it's the other color.
- If you want to avoid using the two variables for old and new positions you can use an image of the board instead and get the pieces as PNG images with transparent backgroud and bliting an image over another one will be way faster than looping over all the casesof each cell
- One thing that reduces the speed of the execution is the fact that you imported the main multiple times and that restarted a new loop in addition to the loop previously executed (in case your Main Game Logic file was main.py)

I Hope it helps.
**One tipp** : don't forget to add the cases of friendly pieces for now so as not to redo parts of your code